# com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, marshalling

I am validating my request with XSD. In my request I set my content as `List <Attribute>`.

Attribute is a POJO:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "attribute", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "value"
})
public class Attribute {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "NCName")
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Object value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

My validation fails with exception:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

How to pass `List<POJO>` for validation ??

Comment: cant you validate the list elements each item a time

Answer (score 0):

you can create a wrapper for this list

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="attributes")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.Field)
    public class{
       @XmlElement(name="attributes")
       private List<Attribute> attributes;
       public void setAttributes(List<Attribute> attributes){
           this.attributes=attributes;}
       public List<Attribute> getAttributes(){
           return this.attributes;}
    }
```

to validate the list of attributes you pass the list of attributes to this wrapper and jaxb will do the rest , we need this class because the parser doesn't accept classes not annotated with xmlRootElement and ArrayList and all its super classes are not annotated  with xmlRootElement 
`java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context`